# sax parsing in android

Tags: android, saxparser

I have to display category name on android textview with array items.here the total category size is 5.

I have wrote the below code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++) {
name[] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
name[].setText(sitesList.getCategory().get(i).toUpperCase());
```

now i have to run the app which means am getting the last (5th) category name alone.But i wish to display the all(total=5) categories.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++) {
 name[i] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
 name[i].setText(sitesList.getCategory().get(i).toUpperCase());
```

Now i have to run the app means my app is force closed.How can i resolve these error ??? please give me solution for these ???

My console window shows:

```
03-12 06:36:08.789: E/AndroidRuntime(886): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 06:36:08.789: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at  com.xmlparsing.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)
03-12 06:36:08.789: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
```

In my code 72th line is :

```
    name[i] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
```

But i have to create the textview programmatically which means its worked well and displayed all(total=5) categories well.

Comment: What's line 72 of MainActivity.java?

Comment: @Phix name[i] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
this is my 72th line

Answer (score 0):

This may not be **the** answer, but it may help get you in the right direction, or at least get you to clarify your intentions.

Based on the `NullPointerException` in the stack, and the only thing that could be causing such an exception on that line is `name[i]`, I'm going to guess that you haven't created the `name` property correctly.

```
TextView [] name = new TextView[5];
```

Even still, there seems to be a better way to do what you're trying to achieve.  In your code, you're trying to access and set the same TextView's text to a new value in each iteration of the loop, so that same TextView's text will always be the last `sitesList.getCategory().get(i)` value.